# expiring image assets referenced from stylesheets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, image

So rails appends timestamps to CSS, JS and image files:

```
image_tag 'foo.png' => 
<img src="foo.png?123123123123' /> # or somethin like that
```

...which is really useful for doing far-future expiration, etc. with Apache's help.

But what about images referenced from stylesheets?  They don't get an appended timestamp.  So it seems to me that it's entirely possible to update one of those images, redeploy, and then *not* see the file change because the browser doesn't think it's been updated.

Unless I'm missing something.

If I'm not, is there a decent solution to this problem?

Comment: Have you considered going back and marking some of your questions as answered?